# Gant, Groovy scp and Ant

Tags: grails, ant, groovy, scp, gant

I'm trying to scp a directory to a remote server, but I'm getting this error. Please help

Exactly one of [file|localfile|remotefile] or one or more nested filesets is required.

```
    ant.scp(todir:"user@mycompany.com:/home/user/db",keyfile:"test.pem") {
        fileset(dir:"/home/test")
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of ant and groovy do you use?
I use ant 1.8.2, groovy 1.8.6, jsch 0.1.46,ant-jsch 1.6.2, ant this script do works:

```
ant = new AntBuilder()
ant.scp(todir:"user1@mycorp.com:~/temp",keyfile:"/tmp/user1.pem",verbose:true, trust:true, passphrase:""){
    fileset(dir:"/user1/temp")
}
```

Comment: I managed to get mine to work the same way as you do as well. :-) Thanks anyway.